MiniflareCoreError: Workers Runtime Failed to Start After Initializing Cloudflare Worker Project
Hope so you all are fine.
I'm setting up a Cloudflare Worker using: npm create cloudflare -- my-app
I tried to run the index.ts file as it was generated, without making any modifications. However, when I try to run the project, I'm encountering the with the given error.
I've Tried So Far:
Checked my Node.js version.
Updated dependencies.
Ensured the TypeScript code is compiled.
Cleared Miniflare cache.
Does anyone know how to fix this or what might be causing the runtime failure?
